# How to cache the static map returned by google maps using PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I studied many forums, some of them saying that I am not allowed and some of them saying I am. Well what I need to do is to cache on the mobile device the image returned by google maps. I am developing an application for iPhone using PhoneGap and jQuery mobile. Can you please tell me how to cache it on the phone's memory for offline use?

Comment: local storage? cf.:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139034/html5-localstorage-for-assets-stylesheets-javascript-images-etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following HTLM5 code to encode it and then store it in the DB:

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```